# Not understanding keyboard values from V2DIP FTDI board

Tags: c, ftdi

I am working on V2DIP FTDI board. After flashing keyboard firmwares such as USBHOSTHidKDB, I'm getting keyboard values as follows:

```
0000040000000000 for 'a' key
0000050000000000 for 'b' key
```

and so on. Does anybody know what these values are? Please help me if you know this concept.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I've improved your title to make it clearer what you are asking about. I suspect you may have to be rather patient for an answer; it will depend on one of rather few people who can answer the question actually seeing it.  I can't help further; I'm too lazy to find the manual for you.  The chances are that the information is in the manual, but you'll need to read it rather carefully.

Comment: It will help if you could provid a link to the manual for the board and a link to the firmware doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB HID usage table specifies the values for the key pressed, page 53 on "USB HID usage Table" (http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/Hut1_12v2.pdf).

Since you haven't give us much about the firmware and its' documentation I can only guess 04 and 05 represent a and b according to the usage table.

Comment: Balakrishna The link helped me alot. Thank you !!